# React-Native (0.64.1) & Notification Extension

Tags: react-native, notifications, cocoapods, share-extension

I am trying to integrate a Notification Extension in my react-native app using the Batch SDK. However I have the following error:

```
‘sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.
```

[image]

Here is my pod file:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'
abstract_target 'BrandName' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"

  target 'BrandNameApp' do
    #Production-specific pods

    target 'BrandNameAppTests' do
        inherit! :complete
        # Pods for testing
    end
  end
  
  target 'BrandNameAppDevelopment' do
      #Development-specific pods
  end
  
  target 'BrandNameAppStage' do
      #Stage-specific pods
  end
  
  target 'RichNotificationsExtension' do
      #Extension-specific pods
      pod 'BatchExtension-ObjC'
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

If I try to put my target `'RichNotificationsExtension'`, else where in my podfile, the module will not be found by the extension file.

I have try to set the "Require Only App-extension-safe API" to "NO" as I have seen in some answers but Xcode won't allow me to build anymore and if I force it in my pod file, the module will not be found either.

Does anyone have a functioning podfile in react-native working with an extension ?

Thanks in advance